# Deleting Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes cluster with missing resource

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Good day,

Accidentally removed network peering, which was done with creating Kubernetes cluster. Now problem is that I want to remove that cluster, but getting error message that this network peering not exists anymore and cluster deletion fails on that.

```
statusMessage: u'Google Compute Engine: There is no peering (gke-ds1f2ds2fdsfdsf5dsf5ds4f-241d-22b7-peer) for the network (GLOBAL:global/PROJECT:121212122121/NETWORK:default).' targetLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/599591769467/zones/region/clusters/cluster-name' zone: region'>] finished with error: Google Compute Engine: There is no peering (gke-ds1f2ds2fdsfdsf5dsf5ds4f-241d-22b7-peer) for the network (GLOBAL:global/PROJECT:599591769467/NETWORK:default)
```

Is there any possible way to force google cloud platform object deletion, even if it have corrupted dependencies?

Comment: Can't you try to remove only the peering from the cluster, then delete it?

Comment: Peering was accidentally removed and now it's not possible to remove cluster which was related to that peering.

Comment: Yeah that I understood... I'm asking you if you tried to change your cluster configuration to remove the peering before deleting the cluster....

Comment: Looking on gcloud docs, I don't see such possibility - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update .

Comment: You could try recreating the peering manually with the same name, if it uses the name in configuration maybe it will take it this way...

Comment: Thank you, recreating peering with same name helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in the comments but I add this one to help someone who may have the same issue.

It seems that the gke cluster need it's network to be in the same states as before to be able to get deleted.

Lucky for us, it's not linked to a peering resource by id or self link and so you just need to recreate the peering with the exact same name to resolve the issue.